# Redirect website from facebook web browser to mobile's default browser

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, mobile

How can I redirect any website from Facebook web browser to mobile default browser.I want to do this using javascript.
I have tried this

```
window.open('', '_system');
```

but didn't work.
Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()
const isFbApp = ['fb_iab', 'fban', 'fbav', 'instagram'].some(app => userAgent.includes(app))
if (!isFbApp) return

const currentLink = location.href
const link = currentLink.replace('http://', '').replace('www.', '')

window.location.href = `intent://${link}#Intent;scheme=https;end`// android
window.location = `googlechrome://${link}`// ios to chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this script it works perfectly, but it redirects to google chrome.

```
<script>
    function isFacebookApp() {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
        return (ua.indexOf("FBAV") > -1) || (ua.indexOf("FBAN") > -1);
    }
if (isFacebookApp()) {
    var currentLink = location.href;
    if (currentLink.indexOf('https') > -1) {
        var currentLink = currentLink.replace('https://', '');
        currentLink = currentLink.replace('www.', '');
        var chromeLink = "intent://" + currentLink + "#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.android.chrome;end";
        window.location.href = chromeLink;
    }
    if (currentLink.indexOf('http') > -1) {
        var currentLink = currentLink.replace('http://', '');
        currentLink = currentLink.replace('www.', '');
        var chromeLink = "intent://" + currentLink + "#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.android.chrome;end";
        window.location.href = chromeLink;
    }
} 
</script>
```